# Take k numbers from the array and xor them with x to get maximum sum

Tags: greedy-algorithms, xor

Given an array A of n numbers and integers k and x. We can perform the following operation any number of times (including zero times). Take exactly k numbers from the array and replace each of them after doing xor with x . For example, we took ith element among k elements, we will replace Ai with Ai ⊕ x . We wish to maximize the sum of elements in the array.

> https://www.codechef.com/problems/LENTMO

I've seen the editorial, I am hoping a simpler explanation here.

Comment: It is definitely a duplicate of that, but the answer there is not correct (fails for case `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Z=2, Q=7`

Comment: @lox https://discuss.codechef.com/t/lentmo-editorial/27148, might help. I think your solution is not complete.